# Set Bundler config for specific version of a gem

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm wanting to install an older version of the Puma gem, using Bundler. Based on [this comment in GitHub](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/718#issuecomment-122632128), I'm able to determine that it needs `--with-opt-include=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` to work.

I'd like to use that option every time I install this gem. I know I can add it to `bundle config`...

```
bundle config build.puma -- --with-opt-include=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

... but I only want that to apply to Puma v2.9.0. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the following ways?

```
gem install puma -v '2.9.0' -- --with-opt-include=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

OR

```
bundle config build.puma /path/to/local/git/puma/2.9.0 -- --with-opt-include=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Comment: The first one still requires _me_ to remember to do it, which was what I was trying to avoid - but with a tweak to the gem path, the second one seems to work perfectly. Here's the generic version: `bundle config build.puma $(dirname $(dirname $(gem which puma))) -- --with-opt-include=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`

Comment: In fact, since I'm using RVM and the gem is installed inside a specific Ruby folder, this should restrict it to that version of Ruby as well :)